# How to avoid numeric exception : overflow in Maple 14?

Tags: exception, overflow, maple

Maple 14 has isprime command which testing whether number is prime or not. It's allowed to write expressions as input data so we may write the next command :

> isprime(2^(3^43-5)-1);

but I get the following error when trying to run a test :

Error, numeric exception: overflow

So my question is how to avoid this overflow error ? Should I change default stack size  and if it's so how to do that on win 7 ultimate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 3^43-5 is composite, then so is 2^(3^43-5)-1. See the wikipedia page on Mersenne primes. And you can get this result quickly in Maple. So if that's all you wanted, then you're done.

```
> isprime( 3^43-5 );
                         false
```

Now, suppose that you had a prime p of comparable size to 3^43. Let's say, the very next prime higher than that.

```
nextprime( 3^43-5 );
                 328256967394537077679

numtheory[mersenne]( nextprime( 3^43-5 ) );
                          FAIL
```

Ok, so that's too unfortunate.

Try applying `isprime` to 2^(10^6+3)-1. (Due to normal evaluation rules of maple procedures, `isprime` gets the expanded argument, so has no chance to see the special form and do the cheaper test against only 10^6+3. That's what `numtheory[mersenne]` is for.) You'll wait a while. Now imagine how long it would take `isprime` to handle a number about 10^11 times as large, which is about what you'd have if you used `2^nextprime(3^43-5)-1`.

Comment: ,In Maple help states that :" if n is prime, but 2^n-1 is not determinably prime, then mersenne(n) will return FAIL"....I don't know what ' determinably ' prime suppose to be.I have tried to test these large numbers with numtheory[mersenne] but I got message FAIL